# Standard Passwort not Accepted – Headless Setup

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi-os, headless

I downloaded the most recent version of Raspberry Pi OS, saved a `wpa_supplicant.conf` and a `ssh` file in the boot partition, but I was not able to ssh to the pi with `ssh pi@raspberry.local` as the standard password `raspberry` did not work.

How can I set up my pi headless without using `rpi-imager` or stuff like that?

Answer (score 16):

There is no standard user and password anymore in the new Raspberry Pi OS image.
https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/

To create one a file named `userconf` has to be saved to the boot partition containing just one line:

`username:<encrypted-password>`

You get the encrypted password by running `echo 'yourpassword' | openssl passwd -6 -stdin` on a linux machine with `openssl` installed.

If you want to use the old standard password `raspberry` and the `pi` username, paste this line to your `userconf`:

`pi:$6$6jHfJHU59JxxUfOS$k9natRNnu0AaeS/S9/IeVgSkwkYAjwJfGuYfnwsUoBxlNocOn.5yIdLRdSeHRiw8EWbbfwNSgx9/vUhu0NqF50`

Comment: password for user `pi` is `bananapi` for 2020-04-10 update Raspbian Stretch, kernel 4.4 for banana pi board.